# recurrence relation bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is the only problem in my analysis class that's anything similar to this and I don't know where to begin.

Let $a_1 > 1$. And $a_{n+1} = 2-\frac1{a_n}$ for $n\ge1$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded monotone sequence and find the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n>1$. By AM-GM $a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\ge 2$. So, $a_n\ge 2-\frac1{a_n}$. Thus, $a_n\ge a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+1}\ge 2- \frac1{a_n}>1$. So, by induction, the sequence is monotone and every term is greater than $1>0$. So, $a_{n+1}=2-\frac1{a_n}<2$. So, the sequence is bounded. As every bounded monotone sequence has limit, $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.

Moreover, use the fact that $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2- \frac{1}{a_n}$$
$$=2-\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}=2-\frac1L$$

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be careful about $a$ vs $A$.  They should not be assumed to be the same.  To prove the sequence is bounded, assume $A_n \lt 2$, and show $A_{n+1} \lt 2$ and you have an induction proof. To prove monotone, assume $A_n \gt 1$ and show $A_{n+1} \lt A_n$